# Flink Cluster 1.13.1 Streaming Job fails with Lost leadership Issues

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Could Someone please assist me How can I come over this Lost Leadership Issue/Error as this causing Real-time jobs to miss the timelines and this happens with the Flink cluster every once a month?

```
   java.lang.Exception: Job leader for job id f7df1578fb94f7b6d8bc1b84ad4649aa lost leadership.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor$JobLeaderListenerImpl.lambda$null$2(TaskExecutor.java:2189)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor$JobLeaderListenerImpl.lambda$jobManagerLostLeadership$3(TaskExecutor.java:2187)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:440)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Hi. Did you enable the checkpointing and recover options ? It not solve the problem, but it can mitigate the real time data loses.

Comment: Yes, the checkpointing is enabled but due to watermarking the events get missed which causes false calculation.

Comment: Can you show the stream definition code ?